# Join one data frame to another by membership in a range

Tags: r

I have two data frames that look like something like the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame(time=seq(0.0, by = 0.003, length.out = 1000))

   time
1 0.000
2 0.003
3 0.006
4 0.009
5 0.012
6 0.015
...

df2 <- data.frame(onset=c(0.0, 0.8, 1.9, 2.4), offset=c(0.799, 1.899, 2.399, 3.0))

  onset offset   A   B
1   0.0  0.799 ... ...
2   0.8  1.899 ... ...
3   1.9  2.399 ... ...
4   2.4  3.000 ... ...
```

In reality there are more columns in each of the data frames, and there are many more times in the first data frame and they're not regularly spaced; there aren't too many more rows in the second data frame. I want to merge the two data frames such that each row in the first data frame gets the extra columns for the appropriate range from the second data frame, and I want to do it efficiently because there are hundreds of thousands of rows involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `findInterval` to match a time with the corresponding `onset`, then `merge` your two data.frames:

```
df1$onset <- df2$onset[findInterval(df1$time, df2$onset)]
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "onset")

head(df3)
#   onset  time offset
# 1     0 0.000  0.799
# 2     0 0.003  0.799
# 3     0 0.006  0.799
# 4     0 0.009  0.799
# 5     0 0.012  0.799
# 6     0 0.015  0.799

tail(df3)
#      onset  time offset
# 995    2.4 2.982      3
# 996    2.4 2.985      3
# 997    2.4 2.988      3
# 998    2.4 2.991      3
# 999    2.4 2.994      3
# 1000   2.4 2.997      3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can prepare a factor for each, then use plyr::join:

```
# breaks for 'cut'
times=c(df2$onset[1],df2$offset)

# modified df1 to shorten the list
df1 <- data.frame(time=seq(0.0, by = 0.03, length.out = 100))

# Add a few columns to df2
df2 <- data.frame(onset=c(0.0, 0.8, 1.9, 2.4), offset=c(0.799, 1.899, 2.399, 3.0), A=c(1,2,3,4), B=c(5,6,7,8))


df2$ranges <-cut(df2$onset,times,include.lowest=T))
df1$ranges <-cut(df1$time,times,include.lowest=T,levels=levels(df2$ranges))

join(df1,df2,by='ranges')

head(join(df1,df2,by='ranges')[-2])
  time onset offset A B
1 0.00     0  0.799 1 5
2 0.03     0  0.799 1 5
3 0.06     0  0.799 1 5
4 0.09     0  0.799 1 5
5 0.12     0  0.799 1 5
6 0.15     0  0.799 1 5
```

Answer (score 1):

A third option using `sqldf` to perform the `conditional join`

```
> head(sqldf("select * 
+            from df1 inner join df2 
+                     on (df1.time between df2.onset and df2.offset)"))
```

Head output:

```
   time onset offset
1 0.000     0  0.799
2 0.003     0  0.799
3 0.006     0  0.799
4 0.009     0  0.799
5 0.012     0  0.799
6 0.015     0  0.799
```

An inner join will get rid of times that don't fit between the range in df2. If you want to keep those times, and have nulls in the onset and offest, just a `left join` instead of `inner join` in the SQL in the `sqldf` function above.