# overlap(intersect) time interval and xts

Tags: r, xts, overlap, intersect

There's two time datasets: data from raincollector -- time interval `ti` with `start`, `end` and rain `p` (total amount of rain per period in mm)

```
ti <- data.frame(
             start = c("2017-06-05 19:30:00", "2017-06-06 12:00:00"),
               end = c("2017-06-05 23:30:00", "2017-06-06 14:00:00"),
                 p = c(16.4, 4.4)
      )

ti[,1] <- as.POSIXct(ti[, 1])
ti[,2] <- as.POSIXct(ti[, 2])
```

and timeseries `ts` from gauging station with `time` and parameter `q`, which is the water discharge (cu. m per sec)

```
ts <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
              time = c("2017-06-05 16:00:00", "2017-06-05 19:00:00",
                       "2017-06-05 21:00:00", "2017-06-05 23:00:00",
                       "2017-06-06 9:00:00", "2017-06-06 11:00:00", "2017-06-06 13:00:00",
                       "2017-06-06 16:00:00", "2017-06-06 17:00:00"),
                 q = c(0.78, 0.84, 0.9, 0.78, 0.78, 0.78, 0.78, 1.22, 1.25)
      )
ts[,1] <- as.POSIXct(ts[,1])
```

I need to intersect timeseries with time interval and create a new column in `ts` with `TRUE/FALSE` if this row in the rain interval (`TRUE`) and if it not (`FALSE`) like this one:

```
                 time    q  rain
1 2017-06-05 16:00:00 0.78 FALSE
2 2017-06-05 19:00:00 0.84 FALSE
3 2017-06-05 21:00:00 0.90  TRUE # there were rain
4 2017-06-05 23:00:00 0.78  TRUE # there were rain
5  2017-06-06 9:00:00 0.78 FALSE
6 2017-06-06 11:00:00 0.78 FALSE
7 2017-06-06 13:00:00 0.78  TRUE # there were rain
8 2017-06-06 16:00:00 1.22 FALSE
9 2017-06-06 17:00:00 1.25 FALSE
```

Have you got any ideas how to apply such simple operation?

Comment: What's the purpose of `p` and `q`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892241/merge-by-range-in-r-applying-loops

Comment: @useR both of them are variables I'm investigating. `p` is the total amount of liquid precipitation (in mm) for the period from `start` to `end`. While `q` is the water discharge of the river

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select ts.*, case when ti.p is not null then 1 else 0 end as rain 
      from ts
      left join ti
      on start <= time and
         time <= end')
```

**Result:**

```
                 time    q rain
1 2017-06-05 16:00:00 0.78    0
2 2017-06-05 19:00:00 0.84    0
3 2017-06-05 21:00:00 0.90    1
4 2017-06-05 23:00:00 0.78    1
5  2017-06-06 9:00:00 0.78    0
6 2017-06-06 11:00:00 0.78    0
7 2017-06-06 13:00:00 0.78    1
8 2017-06-06 16:00:00 1.22    0
9 2017-06-06 17:00:00 1.25    0
```

Comment: we could write `... on time between strt and end`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck We can, but I am generally reluctant to use `between` over `<=` operators as it might not be obvious whether `between` is inclusive or not.