# r merge based on criteria

Tags: r, filter, merge

I am trying to merge two datasets df1, df2.

The data in my 1st dataset (df1) looks like this below

```
     Id       ServiceDate    
    234       2004-02-10
    234       2003-11-05
    234       2002-06-07
 117458       2002-03-14
 117458       2003-03-17
 117458       2004-07-05
2195623       2002-04-12
2195623       2002-08-15
2195623       2002-09-10
```

This is the data in my second dataset (df2)

```
     Id       Effective_Dt     Effct_End_Dt    Capacity    
    234       2004-01-01       2004-12-31      10
    234       2002-01-01       2003-12-31      17        
 117458       2000-03-14       2004-12-31      11
2195623       1995-04-01       2003-05-25      22
2195623       2003-05-26       2004-04-17      27 
2195623       2004-04-18       2004-12-31      25
```

1) I am trying to merge these two datasets by ID
2) Inaddition to merging by="Id" , the Capacity value should be based on the `df1$ServiceDate`  between `df2$Effective_Dt` and `df2$Effct_End_Dt`.

For example, the expected output should look like this below

```
     Id       ServiceDate       Capacity 
    234       2004-02-10        10
    234       2003-11-05        17 
    234       2002-06-07        17
 117458       2002-03-14        11 
 117458       2003-03-17        11
 117458       2004-07-05        11
2195623       2002-04-12        22 
2195623       2003-08-15        27
2195623       2004-09-10        25
```

I can do a merge by Id but not sure how to include the second logic which is including the Capacity based on the date constraint. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overlap(intersect) time interval and xts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880861/overlapintersect-time-interval-and-xts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can do a simple left join and then filter out the rows and columns you don't need...

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% left_join(df2) %>% 
        filter(as.Date(ServiceDate)>=as.Date(Effective_Dt),
               as.Date(ServiceDate)<=as.Date(Effct_End_Dt)) %>% 
        select(-Effective_Dt,
               -Effct_End_Dt)

       Id ServiceDate Capacity
1     234  2004-02-10       10
2     234  2003-11-05       17
3     234  2002-06-07       17
4  117458  2002-03-14       11
5  117458  2003-03-17       11
6  117458  2004-07-05       11
7 2195623  2002-04-12       22
8 2195623  2002-08-15       22
9 2195623  2002-09-10       22
```

Note that the last three `Capacity` figures are different from your answer - which seems to be wrong based on your data.

Comment: that worked, there was an error in the select function but when i run without the select function the results were as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea with fuzzy join:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
```

First convert the date strings to actual dates

```
df2 %>%
  mutate(Effective_Dt = as.Date(Effective_Dt),
         Effct_End_Dt = as.Date(Effct_End_Dt)) -> df2

df1 %>%
  mutate(ServiceDate = as.Date(ServiceDate)) -> df1
```

Then perform a fuzzy_left_join of `df2` to `df1`

```
df1 %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(df2,
                  by = c("Id" = "Id", 
                         "ServiceDate" = "Effective_Dt",
                         "ServiceDate" = "Effct_End_Dt"), #variables to join by
                  match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`)) %>% #function to use for each pair of variables 
  select(c(1,2,6)) #select just needed variables


#output:
     Id.x ServiceDate Capacity
1     234  2004-02-10       10
2     234  2003-11-05       17
3     234  2002-06-07       17
4  117458  2002-03-14       11
5  117458  2003-03-17       11
6  117458  2004-07-05       11
7 2195623  2002-04-12       22
8 2195623  2002-08-15       22
9 2195623  2002-09-10       22
```

other options (after converting to date) include non-equi join in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[df2, on = .(Id = Id, ServiceDate >= Effective_Dt, ServiceDate <= Effct_End_Dt), nomatch = 0]

#output
        Id ServiceDate ServiceDate.1 Capacity
1:     234  2004-01-01    2004-12-31       10
2:     234  2002-01-01    2003-12-31       17
3:     234  2002-01-01    2003-12-31       17
4:  117458  2000-03-14    2004-12-31       11
5:  117458  2000-03-14    2004-12-31       11
6:  117458  2000-03-14    2004-12-31       11
7: 2195623  1995-04-01    2003-05-25       22
8: 2195623  1995-04-01    2003-05-25       22
9: 2195623  1995-04-01    2003-05-25       22
```

and probably `sqldf` which I am not all that familiar with.

data

```
df1 <- read.table(text="Id       ServiceDate    
234       2004-02-10
234       2003-11-05
234       2002-06-07
117458       2002-03-14
117458       2003-03-17
117458       2004-07-05
2195623       2002-04-12
2195623       2002-08-15
2195623       2002-09-10", header = TRUE)


df2 <- read.table(text="Id       Effective_Dt     Effct_End_Dt    Capacity    
234       2004-01-01       2004-12-31      10
234       2002-01-01       2003-12-31      17        
117458       2000-03-14       2004-12-31      11
2195623       1995-04-01       2003-05-25      22
2195623       2003-05-26       2004-04-17      27 
2195623       2004-04-18       2004-12-31      25", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: this works on a small dataset but my dataset has 5 million rows and it is taking for ever. Is there a faster version of this algo ?

Comment: did you try the `data.table` version?

Comment: I will try that.