# Appending columns based on ID and Between Two Dates R

Tags: r, merge, between

This problem has been annoying me for the past couple of hours. I need to merge two data frames together which have a common name variable but differing year variables. I need to conditionally merge based on the year of df1 being between two dates in df2.

The data looks as follows:

```
Name   Year   X
Rob    1990   Red
Bob    1991   Blue
Alice  1992   Yellow
Alice  1994   Blue
```

And

```
Name   startDate  endDate Y
Rob    1989       1994    xxx 
Bob    1982       1993    yyy
Alice  1983       1990    xxx
Alice  1990       1995    hhhh
Alice  2000       2001    gggg
```

I'm interested in getting the Y variable from df2 into df1 like so:

```
Name   Year   X      Y
Rob    1990   Red    xxx
Bob    1991   Blue   yyy 
Alice  1992   Yellow hhhh
Alice  1994   Blue   hhhh
```

Merging by speakers, of course, does not fit the data and my attempts at creating a for loop with an if statement are falling flat.

If anyone can help, I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/11892241/5325862

Comment: Maybe a non-equi join with `data.table`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289405/dplyr-left-join-by-less-than-greater-than-condition

Comment: Sort of -- although I suspect there are easier answers out there