# index from one vector to another by closest values

Tags: r, search

Given two sorted vectors, how can you get the index of the closest values from one onto the other.

For example, given:

```
a = 1:20
b = seq(from=1, to=20, by=5)
```

how can I efficiently get the vector

```
c = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
```

which, for each value in `a`, provides the index of the largest value in `b` that is less than or equal to it. But the solution needs to work for unpredictable (though sorted) contents of `a` and `b`, and needs to be fast when `a` and `b` are large.

Comment: Also have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10474590/10488504

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `findInterval`, which constructs a sequence of intervals given by breakpoints in `b` and returns the interval indices in which the elements of `a` are located (see also `?findInterval` for additional arguments, such as behavior at interval boundaries).

```r
a = 1:20
b = seq(from = 1, to = 20, by = 5)

findInterval(a, b)
#>  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: Cool. Can this also be adapted for the closest values that are greater than or equal?

Comment: `findInterval(a, c(-Inf, b), left.open = TRUE)` or `findInterval(a, b, left.open = TRUE) + 1` may be sufficient. This will give index `length(b) + 1` to values in `a` that are larger than `max(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cut`

```
as.integer(cut(a, breaks = unique(c(b-1, Inf)), labels = seq_along(b)))

#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: Fails if there are duplicates in b; returns a factor instead of a vector