# Rank corresponding to next available date from another dataframe

Tags: r

Can someone help me with the below requirement?

DF1:

```
 Item       Day            Rank
  A     2020-01-12
  A     2020-01-13
  B     2020-01-13
```

DF2:

```
  Item        Day            Rank
   A       2020-01-10         1
   A       2020-01-11         2
   A       2020-01-14         3
   B       2020-01-14         4
   B       2020-01-17         5
```

If we have Day in DF1 which is not present in DF2, then I want to fetch the rank for DF1 date from the next date corresponding to the date in DF2.
Here 2020-01-12 in DF1 doesn't have any rank so it should search from DF2 for the next date which is 2020-01-13 & the corresponding rank should be coming as output.

Final Output(DF1):

```
 Item       Day            Rank
  A     2020-01-12          3
  A     2020-01-13          3
  B     2020-01-13          4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findInterval` like:

```
DF1$Rank <- DF2$Rank[findInterval(DF1$Day, c(0,DF2$Day), left.open = TRUE)]
DF1
#         Day Rank
#1 2020-01-12    3
#2 2020-01-15    5
```

In case *DF2* is not sorted:

```
i <- order(DF2$Day)
j <- findInterval(DF1$Day, c(0,DF2$Day[i]), left.open = TRUE)
DF1$Rank <- DF2$Rank[i[j]]
```

Or in case *DF2$Rank* is `1:nrow(DF2)` and `DF2` is sorted.

```
DF1$Rank <- findInterval(DF1$Day, c(0,DF2$Day), left.open = TRUE)
```

Data:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(Day=as.Date(c("2020-01-12", "2020-01-15")), Rank=NA)
DF2 <- data.frame(Day=as.Date(c("2020-01-10", "2020-01-11", "2020-01-13"
  , "2020-01-14", "2020-01-17")), Rank=1:5)
```

For the *updated Question*:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(Item=c("A","A","B"), Day=as.Date(c("2020-01-12", "2020-01-13", "2020-01-13")), Rank=NA)
DF2 <- data.frame(Item=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",2)), Day=as.Date(c("2020-01-10", "2020-01-11", "2020-01-14", "2020-01-14", "2020-01-17")), Rank=1:5)

DF1$Rank <- unlist(sapply(unique(DF1$Item), function(i) {DF2$Rank[DF2$Item==i][findInterval(DF1$Day[DF1$Item==i], c(0,DF2$Day[DF2$Item==i]), left.open = TRUE)]}))
DF1
#  Item        Day Rank
#1    A 2020-01-12    3
#2    A 2020-01-13    3
#3    B 2020-01-13    4
```

**Have also a look at [Join one data frame to another by membership in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10474590/10488504)**

Comment: Need a logic for the day with respect to each Item. Can you please help in identifying the logic for the same.

Comment: @AnshulSaravgi Can you clarify if `DF2` is *sorted* or not and if `DF2$Rank` is simply `1:nrow(DF2)` or not?

Comment: DF2 = as.data.frame(DF2 %>% group_by(Item) %>%
                              mutate(rank = rank(Day)) %>%
                              arrange(Day))

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution (assuming your column `Day` in both `DF1` and `DF2` are already of class `Date`)

```
DF1 <- do.call(rbind,
               c(make.row.names = F,
                 lapply(split(DF1,DF1$Item), function(v) {
                   z <- subset(DF2,Item == unique(v$Item))
                   v <- within(v, Rank <- findInterval(Day, z$Day)+ min(z$Rank))
                   }
                   )
                 )
               )
```

such that

```
> DF1
  Item        Day Rank
1    A 2020-01-12    3
2    A 2020-01-13    3
3    B 2020-01-13    4
```

**DATA**

```
DF1 <- structure(list(Item = c("A", "A", "B"), Day = structure(c(18273, 
18274, 18274), class = "Date"), Rank = c(NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

DF2 <- structure(list(Item = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), Day = structure(c(18271, 
18272, 18275, 18275, 18278), class = "Date"), Rank = 1:5), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding - I have multiple rows in the DF1 then correspondingly I want to find the rank from DF2 based on next available Day

Comment: There is slight change in the requirement. Need a logic for the day with respect to each Item. Can you please help in identifying the logic for the same

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fuzzy_join`

```
library(dplyr)
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, by = c("Item" = "Item", "Day" = "Day"), 
           match_fun = list(`==`, `<=`)) %>%
   group_by(Item.x, Day.x) %>%
   slice(1L) %>%
   mutate(Rank.x = coalesce(as.integer(Rank.x), Rank.y)) %>%
   select(-ends_with("y")) %>%
   rename_all(~names(df1))

#  Item       Day         Rank
#  <fct>     <date>     <int>
#1   A     2020-01-12     3
#2   A     2020-01-13     3
#3   B     2020-01-13     4
```

Comment: If we increment the Day value by 1 then that Day is also not present. Let's assume in DF2 day 2020-01-12 & 2020-01-13 both are not present then day 2020-01-14 rank should be considered

Comment: There is slight change in the requirement. Need a logic for the day with respect to each Item. Can you please help in identifying the logic for the same

Comment: Thanks Ronak but it is taking quite a lot of time for just 32k rows